# change the info part of each node in binary tree

Tags: data-structures

i have a binary tree.

```
         2
       /   \
      3     4
     / \     \
    5  1      8
     \       /
     6      9
```

I want to change the info part of each node such that the

```
nodeinfo = nodeinfo + nextInorderNodeInfo
```

so the actual inorder traversal

```
5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 9, 8
```

will change to

```
5+6,6+3,3+1,1+2,2+4,4+9,9+8,8+0 

11, 9,  4,  3,  6,  13, 17, 8
```

i need to write a function that will modify the binary tree info parts of each node.

i have done the following

calling

```
change(root,NULL);
```

function definition

```
void change(node* n, node *k)
{
 if (n) 
  { 
    if (n->left) change(n->left,n);
    if (n->right) change(n,n->right);
    n->info + = k->info;
  }
}
```

in this way i am not able to modify the nodes that are right hand leaf nodes.

can someone give the correct solution..???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a **reverse** in-order traversal function (as in `right, this, left` rather than `left, this, right`) (which is technically still in-order, just with a different definition, but that's besides the point).

So this function will process the nodes in this order:

```
8, 9, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5
```

This function must also remember the last processed node's value (before you added to it) and simply add this value to the current node.

And here's even some code which *should* work:

```
int last = 0;
void change(node* n)
{
  if (n) 
  {
    change(n->right);
    int tempLast = n->info;
    n->info += last;
    last = tempLast;
    change(n->left);
  }
}
```